# GoogleSheets SumIFS in array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to convert my Sumifs formula into an array formula
(so that the sheet auto updates)

I'm struggling to do so though

I tried using sumif formula and combining the columns, but I can't get it to work right.

I created this simplified version of my data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qnoY_MZTup8XLLWCu61-Ifiv8dak6QRc1CxsGKpmFWE/edit?usp=sharing

(I know there's only two rows, but in my actual data there's a lot more and the number of brands vary)

I've shown in column C on sheet 2 how the sumifs formula works.
But ideally I'd like an array formula in cell B2 that will populate all the rows for me (instead of having to fill down the sumifs each time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `arrayformula` for this. You can simply use `query`:

#### Formula (A2):

```
=query({Sheet1!A2:D}, "select Col1, sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null and Col2 is null and Col3 is null group by Col1 label sum(Col4) ''")
```

This will populate both A and B.

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for that, I actually had a few other array formulas in different columns. 
This had made me think I can do it all with a single query formula instead

Comment: @MichaelLiew, Yes, you should be able to do it. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)